# Create histogram with specific values in x and y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, jupyter

I have the following dataframe

```
    COD     DATE         QTD            MOV             SUM
1   15295   2021-01-22    1             10.0             3
3   15801   2020-12-04    1             10.0             1
4   23369   2021-01-01    1             7.5              6
11  32012   2020-07-26    1             10.0             2
12  37726   2020-06-30    1             10.0             1
```

I want to make a histogram where on the x axis there are values from the column SUM (ordenated) and on the y axis are the number of COD that have the value of SUM on the x axis.
I tried making a histogram and moving the number of bins but not much success.
Maybe it has to be done with a bar graph? But how do I select what I want to put on the y axis? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and then [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
r = range(df['SUM'].min(), df['SUM'].max() + 1)
s = df['SUM'].value_counts().reindex(r, fill_value=0)
print (s)
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
Name: SUM, dtype: int64

s.plot.bar()
```

Or use [`Series.plot.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.hist.html):

```
df['SUM'].plot.hist()
```

Comment: On the x axis it appears all the COD's. Is it possible to get a number? Like 5 COD have 3 SUM for example?

Comment: On the x the number of COD (like aggregated - 1,2,3,...) and on the y the number of SUM. One would read the graph like 5 COD's (from the x axis) have 3 SUM for example.

Comment: I think so. Count the number of COD that a have certain value in SUM and plot these.

Comment: I don't have an example graph. But maybe some preprocessing needs to be made? Like get a dataframe with the values from the result of count COD and the values of SUM? To make it easier to plot

Comment: The x axis with COD count and the y axis with SUM values. only that

Comment: Actually I just realised it should be SUM in x axis and cound COD in y axis because otherwise the x axis wouldn't work. But from the sample data, on the x axis like 1,2,3,.. and on the y axis the number of COD that have the value SUM (would also be a numeric axis fom 1 to the top number of count COD). Sorry for the mistake

Comment: x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and y = 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1

Comment: Thank you! Huge help!